# gcloud Firestore export does not export sub-collections

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

I am running the following command to export my Firestore collection.

```
gcloud alpha firestore export gs://[...] --collection-ids='[...]'
```

The resulting export only contains documents at root level, but not any sub-collection under any documents.

How can I export all sub-collections from my collection?

I am following this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/export-import) from google.

Answer (score 11):

To back up also sub-collections, I have to specify the collection ids of sub-collections.

```
gcloud alpha firestore export gs://[...] --collection-ids='[COLLECTION_ID]','[SUB_COLLECTION_ID_1]','[SUB_COLLECTION_ID_2]'
```

Without `--collection-ids` option, it can also back up the whole firestore including all sub-collections. But specific collection cannot be imported from this backup.

Comment: I encountered the same problem and was glad to find your solution. But for me, I found that sub collections are stored in separately folders. Is there any specific format in the --collection-ids? I used something like "--collection_ids='main','sub1','sub2'" and found that there are 3 folders of main, sub1 and sub2

Comment: @kee I also had the same observation. But it is not a problem since I tried to import all the collection ids in a new project and it retained original subcollection structure.

Comment: What is the format of a `SUB_COLLECTION_ID`? Let's say I have a `customers` collection with an `orders` subcollection: would this be referenced as `customers.orders`, `customers/orders`, or `customers/{doc_id}/orders`?

Comment: @JoséDavidAroesti just use `orders`.

Comment: @Michael this doesn't work for me on subcollections. The export seems successfull but actually comes out empty. Firebase does not complain if a given collection does not exist, but apparently I can't define subcollections.

Comment: I have root collections with SAME NAME than subcollection... how to do ? It merge  both of them : I have `users` and `event/users` => I want get the second one

Comment: @DamienRomito I think you have to report this issue to Google.